# User Defined Function in Esper

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

I am feeding this data to my engine:

```
    {   productID: 1, recipeID: 12345, precentageCompleted: 0, timeStamp: 13:22, indexOfRecipeToExecute: --- }
    {   productID: 1, recipeID: 12345, precentageCompleted: 0, timeStamp: 13:25, indexOfRecipeToExecute: --- }                      
    {   productID: 1, recipeID: 12345, precentageCompleted: 0, timeStamp: 13:27, indexOfRecipeToExecute: --- }
    {   productID: 1, recipeID: 12345, precentageCompleted: 20, timeStamp: 13:30, indexOfRecipeToExecute: --- }                     

    {   productID: 2, recipeID: 6789, precentageCompleted: 0, timeStamp: 13:28-, indexOfRecipeToExecute: -- }
    {   productID: 2, recipeID: 6789, precentageCompleted: 10, timeStamp: 13:30-, indexOfRecipeToExecute: -- }
    {   productID: 2, recipeID: 6789, precentageCompleted: 10, timeStamp: 13:32-, indexOfRecipeToExecute: -- }
```

Actually, these are the products that are already in production and each product has different productID, but recipeID could be the same for numerous products.

Now before sending a new product for production, I need to check whether a different product with the same recipeID is already in production or not???
If this is the case then do not send such product for production, in fact choose some other.

How can I implement such a function in esper?????

Comment: Is it up to Esper to remember that a different product with the same recipeID is already in production, based on the events being sent? Or is that information something that comes from outside? and a user-defined function should fetch that information?

Comment: Yes that information is passed and stored using esper.

Comment: So all that data is saved in esper, and before sending another product to production, I need to check whether I can proceed or not.

Comment: if( newProduct.recipeId == previousProducts.recipeId ){
                                   
    if(previousProducts.precentageCompleted > 70){
                                                     
           //SEND  EVENT TO START PRODUCTION.
        }                                          
    else{
          //SEND  EVENT TO NOT START PRODUCTION.
           }
}
else{
                        //SEND  EVENT TO START PRODUCTION.}